# How to set BindingExpression.Status to Active programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am transfering FrameworkElement from StackPanel on WPF Page to  programmatically created StackPanel. At a certain point I need to refresh bindings and get property values.

At this point `FrameworkElement.DataContext` has correct value and `BindingExpression.Status==BindingStatus.Unattached` for all binding expressions. I execute `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget`, but property values are empty.

I found source code for BindingExpression.UpdateTarget():

```
    public override void UpdateTarget() 
    {
        if (Status == BindingStatus.Detached) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.BindingExpressionIsDetached)); 

        if (Worker != null) 
        {
            Worker.RefreshValue();  // calls TransferValue
        }
    }
```

Worker gets instance in internal override void `BindingExpression.Activate()`. Also inside  Activate() BindingExpression.Status set to BindingStatus.Active.

How can I programmatically initiate execution for `BindingExpression.Activate()` and make UpdateTarget after that?

### Update

Solution here (thanks, Olli):

```
public  void UpdateAllBindingTargets( DependencyObject obj)
    {

        FrameworkElement visualBlock = obj as FrameworkElement;
        if (visualBlock==null)
            return;
        if (visualBlock.DataContext==null)
            return;
        Object objDataContext = visualBlock.DataContext;

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DependencyProperty, BindingExpression>> allElementBinding = GetAllBindings(obj);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<DependencyProperty, BindingExpression> bindingInfo in allElementBinding)
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(obj, bindingInfo.Key);

            Binding myBinding = new Binding(bindingInfo.Value.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
            myBinding.Source = objDataContext;
            visualBlock.SetBinding(bindingInfo.Key, myBinding);
            BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(visualBlock, bindingInfo.Key).UpdateTarget();

        }

    }
```

where getting all bindings for object:

```
public  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DependencyProperty, BindingExpression>> GetAllBindings( DependencyObject obj)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<DependencyObject>();

        stack.Push(obj);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var cur = stack.Pop();
            var lve = cur.GetLocalValueEnumerator();

            while (lve.MoveNext())
                if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(cur, lve.Current.Property))
                {
                    KeyValuePair<DependencyProperty,BindingExpression> result=new KeyValuePair<DependencyProperty, BindingExpression>(lve.Current.Property,lve.Current.Value as BindingExpression);
                    yield return result;
                }

            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cur);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cur, i);
                if (child is FrameworkElement)
                    stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it has an answer added as an addendum to the question. Would you move that to a self-answer please, Frank? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically create a new binding, which should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#creating_a_binding

Example from the MSDN page

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think i can recreate all bindings, but I founding method for activate exists bindings. And what BindingExpression.Status will be set for new bindings?

Comment: BindingExpression.Status is `Active` for new bindings.

Comment: If my answer was correct and helped you, could you mark it as the answer for the question? If not, could you specify the question?